# Proxy Configuration for Liferay IDE with Ivy

Tags: proxy, liferay, config, ivy

I try to create new Lifreay-Plugin project with Liferay-IDE 2.0. But I get Ivy Network Problem. I think it is necessary to config proxy for Ivy, but I don't know where to do this.

Here the Exception:

```
[Console output redirected to file:D:\Liferays\6.2.CE-RC5\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\com.liferay.ide.sdk.core\sdk.log]
Buildfile: D:\Liferays\6.2.CE-RC5\liferay-plugins-sdk-6.2.0\themes\build.xml
      [get] Getting: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/ivy/ivy/2.3.0/ivy-2.3.0.jar
      [get] To: D:\Liferays\6.2.CE-RC5\liferay-plugins-sdk-6.2.0\.ivy\ivy-2.3.0.jar
      [get] Error getting http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/ivy/ivy/2.3.0/ivy-2.3.0.jar to D:\Liferays\6.2.CE-RC5\liferay-plugins-sdk-6.2.0\.ivy\ivy-2.3.0.jar

BUILD FAILED
D:\Liferays\6.2.CE-RC5\liferay-plugins-sdk-6.2.0\themes\build.xml:5: The following error occurred while executing this line:
D:\Liferays\6.2.CE-RC5\liferay-plugins-sdk-6.2.0\build-common-plugins.xml:5: The following error occurred while executing this line:
D:\Liferays\6.2.CE-RC5\liferay-plugins-sdk-6.2.0\build-common.xml:47: The following error occurred while executing this line:
D:\Liferays\6.2.CE-RC5\liferay-plugins-sdk-6.2.0\build-common-ivy.xml:17: java.net.UnknownHostException: repo1.maven.org
```

With maven the behavior is well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

put the proxy definition to Liferay-SDK/build-common-ivy.xml

e.g. there:

```
<if>
    <not>
        <available file="${ivy.home}/ivy-${ivy.version}.jar" />
    </not>
    <then>
        <mkdir dir="${ivy.home}" />
        <setproxy proxyhost="PROXY_SERVER_XX.XX..." proxyport="e.g.8080" proxyUser="USER-if-not-annonym"    proxyPassword="USER-password-if-necessary"/>  
        <get
            dest="${ivy.home}"
            src="${ivy.jar.url}"
        />
    </then>
</if>
```